# How to show rotation directions of a cube in tikz 3dplot

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-3dplot, arc

I try to semicircular arrows with heads on both ends.
All of them should have their center around O.
They should mark the rotation directions of the drawn cube.
For example one semicircular arrow will start in S1, touch S2 and end in S3. So in total their should be 6 arrows.

I tried around for two hours now and just don't get the functionality of "arc". All I get is [image]

May anybody provide me with a hint or solution how to get where i want to?

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\trimbox{6.8cm 0cm 0cm 0cm}{
\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{60}{70}{35}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [tdplot_rotated_coords,
        cube/.style={black},
        arr/.style={-latex,color=green!70,thick,line cap=round,shorten <= 1.5pt}]

\coordinate (A1) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (0,1,0);
\coordinate (A3) at (1,1,0);
\coordinate (A4) at (1,0,0);
\coordinate (B1) at (0,0,1);
\coordinate (B2) at (0,1,1);
\coordinate (B3) at (1,1,1);
\coordinate (B4) at (1,0,1);
\coordinate (O) at ($(A1)!0.5!(B3)$);
\coordinate (S1) at ($(A1)!0.5!(B2)$);
\coordinate (S2) at ($(B2)!0.5!(A3)$);
\coordinate (S3) at ($(A3)!0.5!(B4)$);
\coordinate (S4) at ($(B4)!0.5!(A1)$);
\coordinate (S5) at ($(B1)!0.5!(B3)$);
\coordinate (S6) at ($(A1)!0.5!(A3)$);

\draw[cube] (B1) -- (B2) -- (B3) -- (B4) -- cycle;
\draw[cube] (A2) -- (B2);
\draw[cube] (A3) -- (B3);


\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0]
\draw[arr] (0:0.5) arc (90:0:-0.5) ;
\draw[arr] (0:0.5) arc (-180:0:-0.5) ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=0]
\draw[arr] (0:0.5) arc (180:0:-0.5) ;
\draw[arr] (0:0.5) arc (-180:0:-0.5) ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0]
\draw[arr] (0:0.5) arc (180:0:-0.5) ;
\draw[arr] (0:0.5) arc (-180:0:-0.5) ;
\end{scope}

\draw[cube] (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- cycle;
\draw[cube] (A1) -- (B1);
\draw[cube] (A4) -- (B4);

\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you want two arrows to appear as one, you shouldn't be using shorten or line cap=round as is done using arr/.style.   For that matter, one can just as easily create an arc with two arrowheads as one.  Lastly, the starting point is (O) +(0:0.5), and try not to use negative radii.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original code is actually very close to what you ask for, if you take John Kormylo's advice and use `(O) +`... for your starting coordinates and fix the first arc to start at 180 degrees instead of 90.

Unfortunately, the resulting diagram is quite cluttered and it is very hard (in my opinion) to interpret the arcs properly in 3D. One thing which might help is to use doubled lines to reinforce the idea that some of your lines are "in front" of others. I've also added the `bending` library, which makes the arrowheads look a little less awkward, and placed the arrowheads along their respective circles so that they don't all point to the same place.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{bending}

\begin{document}
\trimbox{6.8cm 0cm 0cm 0cm}{
\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{60}{70}{35}%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
      tdplot_rotated_coords,
      cube/.style={white, double=black, double distance=.1mm, join=bevel},
      arr/.style={-{latex[color=green!70]},
        white, double=green!70, shorten <= 1pt, shorten >=1pt
      }
    ]

\coordinate (A1) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (0,1,0);
\coordinate (A3) at (1,1,0);
\coordinate (A4) at (1,0,0);
\coordinate (B1) at (0,0,1);
\coordinate (B2) at (0,1,1);
\coordinate (B3) at (1,1,1);
\coordinate (B4) at (1,0,1);
\coordinate (O) at ($(A1)!0.5!(B3)$);
\draw[cube] (B1) -- (B2) -- (B3) -- (B4) -- cycle
  (A2) -- (B2)
  (A3) -- (B3);

% These must be drawn back to front
\draw[arr, canvas is zx plane at y=0] (O) +(0:0.5) arc (0:-180:0.5);
\draw[arr, canvas is yz plane at x=0] (O) +(0:0.5) arc (0:180:0.5);
\draw[arr, canvas is xy plane at z=0] (O) +(180:0.5) arc (180:0:0.5);
\draw[arr, canvas is xy plane at z=0] (O) +(180:0.5) arc (-180:0:0.5);
\draw[arr, canvas is yz plane at x=0] (O) +(0:0.5) arc (0:-180:0.5);
\draw[arr, canvas is zx plane at y=0] (O) +(0:0.5) arc (0:180:0.5);

\draw[cube] (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- cycle
  (A1) -- (B1)
  (A4) -- (B4);

\end{tikzpicture}
}

\end{document}
```

[image: rotating cube]

Answer (score 2):

I redefined `arr` as a two headed arrow, and added a dot at `(O)`.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\trimbox{6.8cm 0cm 0cm 0cm}{
\tdplotsetmaincoords{0}{0}
\tdplotsetrotatedcoords{60}{70}{35}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
    [tdplot_rotated_coords,
        cube/.style={black},
        arr/.style={latex-latex,color=green!70,thick}]

\coordinate (A1) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (A2) at (0,1,0);
\coordinate (A3) at (1,1,0);
\coordinate (A4) at (1,0,0);
\coordinate (B1) at (0,0,1);
\coordinate (B2) at (0,1,1);
\coordinate (B3) at (1,1,1);
\coordinate (B4) at (1,0,1);
\coordinate (O) at ($(A1)!0.5!(B3)$);
\coordinate (S1) at ($(A1)!0.5!(B2)$);
\coordinate (S2) at ($(B2)!0.5!(A3)$);
\coordinate (S3) at ($(A3)!0.5!(B4)$);
\coordinate (S4) at ($(B4)!0.5!(A1)$);
\coordinate (S5) at ($(B1)!0.5!(B3)$);
\coordinate (S6) at ($(A1)!0.5!(A3)$);

\draw[cube] (B1) -- (B2) -- (B3) -- (B4) -- cycle;
\draw[cube] (A2) -- (B2);
\draw[cube] (A3) -- (B3);

\fill (O) circle[radius=1pt];

\begin{scope}[canvas is zy plane at x=0]
\draw[arr] (O) +(90:0.5) arc (90:-90:0.5) ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is zx plane at y=0]
\draw[arr] (O) +(90:0.5) arc (90:-90:0.5) ;
\end{scope}

\begin{scope}[canvas is yx plane at z=0]
\draw[arr] (O) +(90:0.5) arc (90:-90:0.5) ;
\end{scope}

\draw[cube] (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- cycle;
\draw[cube] (A1) -- (B1);
\draw[cube] (A4) -- (B4);

\end{tikzpicture}}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]